# How to load large amount of data into CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-design, plist

I have a CoreData database that gets initialized with a local file.
The CoreData schema that looks like this:

```
Category -->> Objections -->> Responses -->> Evidence
```

("-->>" means, has many)

Each entity also has a description that can be anywhere from 2 to thousands of characters long, stored in an NSString.

**Question:** How can I store this data so that it would be easy for someone to edit without having to know a lot about programming? (But also follow best practices)

Currently, I am thinking of these as possible approaches:

1) Store everything in 1 big plist file. This would be about 25 pages long.
2) Separate each entity into it's own PList file, and relate each the values with an ID#, like a Relational Data Base. This would make the files a more manageable size, but you have to keep track of ID#.
3) Same as above, but with JSON

Comment: Any of those options sound like asking for trouble if they're going to be edited by a person who doesn't know a lot about programming. If the syntax in the file isn't exactly right, they'll all end up as garbage that someone has to clean up.

Comment: You're probably right. Any suggestions?

Comment: A few possibilities: (1) Have these people edit a spreadsheet and save as CSV, then use a custom script to convert the data to plist or JSON format, (2) Use a plist editor like [PlistEdit Pro](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/), or (3) write a custom data entry app that reads and writes your data model and which these people can use.

Comment: that comes close to my answer.. I might also do this! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a dead simple desktop application that uses Core Data.  Let the people edit the file in that desktop application and keep it stored in Core Data.  Then when you ship your application you can embed that SQLite file into your iOS application so there is no start up parsing required.

Standing up an OS X app for this that doesn't need to be pretty is dead simple.  Takes an afternoon or two at most and saves you a ton of headaches.

Comment: Recently did something similar, using a Mac target to create canned data for an app, then put the resulting .sqlite file into the iOS app bundle. Got dirty looks for doing this; thanks for making me feel less stupid.

Comment: I did exactly this myself. It makes life much easier to create / maintain the data in a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

run in simulator, do the parsing of the plist OR CSV (might be easier, since thats an excel compatible format) **there** (in the simulated app) and then copy the resulting DB to your xcode project and ship it.

=> your 'content provider' can work with excel

=> you don't have to ship a CSV (or whatever file you use) since you have a filled DB after you parsed it in the simulator

Comment: Editing data in the simulator is a painful experience.  Digging out the SQLite file from the ~/Library directory is not exciting either for non-developers.

Comment: thats why I didn't propose it. I proposed PARSING it there

Comment: :) I'd not write a custom app even if trivial IF I can avoid it. If editing is WAY complex, then yes, but normally excel and maybe some formulas work (in my experience)

Comment: Writing a desktop app to edit Core Data takes virtually zero time with the integration between IB and Core Data.  It is nearly a zero code app that gets written once.

Comment: maybe it is us or only me but not many 'non-techy' people use osx. ;) thats why. Im well aware that it is almost NO work :)

Comment: I didn't vote on it or anything: im just saying that given the circumstances I wouldn't write an app but rather try to use something existing

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra can you give a link describing the connection between coredata and IB? Thank you

Comment: @EminIsrafiliOS [Here is an ancient example](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php). You would need to do some research on how to do this in Xcode 5 but it is a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice post from Mattt Thompson about Core Data Libraries & Utilities: http://nshipster.com/core-data-libraries-and-utilities/, maybe something fit for you. =]